# $u_n\to u \implies u_n'(x)\to u'(x)$ if $u_n, u\in C^1(I)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I$ be a closed bounded interval (will this matter?). Let $u_n(x)$ be a sequence of $C^1(I)$ functions such that $u_n\to u\in C^1(I)$. It seems we should have in that case (is it true?) that $u_n'(x)\to u'(x)$. But I am not sure if or why I can swap the two limits $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}u_n'(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{u_n(x+h)-u_n(x)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{u_n(x+h)-u_n(x)}{h}=u'(x)$.

Comment: The usual norm on $C^{1}(I)$ is $\|u\|_{\infty}+\|u'\|_{\infty}$ If this is the norm you are using then the result is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether this is true depends on what you mean by the hypothesis $u_n\to u$. If you mean convergence in the usual norm for $C^1(I)$ then this implies $u_n'\to u'$ more or less just by definition. But assuming just $u_n\to u$ uniformly is not enough.

For example let $$u_n(t)=\sin(n^2t)/n.$$Then $u_n\to0$ uniformly on $\Bbb R$ but $u_n'(0)$ diverges as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you. I think it is more clear. So actually is $u\in L^1(I)\setminus W^{1,1}(I)$? were $I=[-1,1]$ for instance and $W^{1,1}$ is the Sobolev space? (I just started to read about Sobolev spaces)

Comment: @roi_saumon ??? $u=0$.

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake

Comment: Another thing I am not sure about. From your example it is clear that it is possible that $u_n'(t)\not\to u'(t)$ for some $t$. But will we have $u_n'(t)\to u(t)$ almost everywhere?

Comment: @roi_saumon No, it's not too hard to give an example where $u_n\to0$ uniformly but $u_n'(t)$ is unbounded for _every_ $t$.